# How do I upgrade 'wicd' to the latest version?

Tags: apt, command-line, updates, software-center, wicd

Tried sudo apt-get upgrade wicd, but it gave an error: `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome...404 Not Found`

Why is it looking for google chrome???

How to upgrade Wicd to latest version?

Also tried the software center. There is a remove button for Wicd but no upgrade button.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of *wicd* in the Ubuntu repositories for 12.04 is **1.7.2.3-1ubuntu0.1**.

To upgrade a specific package(s) via *apt-get*, you simply use `install`, not `upgrade`, e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

If a newer version is available, it will be upgraded, otherwise *apt-get* will tell you:

```
wicd is already the newest version.
```

---

The Chrome thing looks like a PPA you added which is no longer available for your Ubuntu version. `upgrade` tries to upgrade *all* packages from *all* repositories, hence the 404 error. It doesn't matter unless you want to install/upgrade Chrome, but you can remove that PPA from Software Sources to get rid of the message.

Comment: Thanks. OK, I got wicd is already the newest version. I guess because I am running Ubunutu 11.04...? Is that why it is 1.7.0?